# Error when booting ISO partition from syslinux

Tags: linux, iso-image, bootloader

My partition table is as follows:
/dev/sda
- /dev/sda1 Arch Linux (200G)
- /dev/sda2 Swap (16G)
- /dev/sda3 Recovery (1G)
- /dev/sda4 Extended
- - /dev/sda5 Arch_201212 (256M)
- Free Space (15G)

I have used `dd` to write the newest arch-linux installation ISO to /dev/sda5. If I mount the partition, all the files are there. The recovery partition contains only the syslinux loader for the purpose of starting the various partitions after /dev/sda4.

When I load the entry, it says:

> Booting...
>   isolinux.bin missing or corrupt

Then it tries to boot using PXE/Network Adapter, which obviously fails.

Although it is *not* missing. It is in [ /dev/sda5 ]/isolinux/isolinux.bin

Here is my `syslinux.cfg` in /dev/sda3

> DEFAULT arch-recovery
>   PROMPT 0
>   TIMEOUT 100
>   UI menu.c32
>   MENU TITLE Recovery Partition
>   MENU COLOR border       30;44   #40ffffff #a0000000 std
>   MENU COLOR title        1;36;44 #9033ccff #a0000000 std
>   MENU COLOR sel          7;37;40 #e0ffffff #20ffffff all
>   MENU COLOR unsel        37;44   #50ffffff #a0000000 std
>   MENU COLOR help         37;40   #c0ffffff #a0000000 std
>   MENU COLOR timeout_msg  37;40   #80ffffff #00000000 std
>   MENU COLOR timeout      1;37;40 #c0ffffff #00000000 std
>   MENU COLOR msg07        37;40   #90ffffff #a0000000 std
>   MENU COLOR tabmsg       31;40   #30ffffff #00000000 std
>   LABEL arch-recovery
>           MENU LABEL Arch Linux Live CD
>           COM32 chain.c32
>           APPEND hd0 5
>   LABEL hdt
>           MENU LABEL HDT (Hardware Detection Tool)
>           COM32 hdt.c32
>   LABEL reboot
>           MENU LABEL Reboot
>           COM32 reboot.c32
>   LABEL off
>           MENU LABEL Power Off
>           COMBOOT poweroff.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using Knoppix.

> - create a mountpoint to mount the ISO with loopback:
>
>   ```
>   mkdir /mnt/LiveISO
>   ```
> - mount the image:
>
>   ```
>   mount -t iso9660 -o loop,ro /DOWNLOADS/Knoppix-3.7-en.iso /mnt/LiveISO
>   ```
> - create a directory on the device where you are going to boot from:
>
>   ```
>   mkdir /mnt/hda4/KNOPPIX
>   ```
> - copy the contents of the mounted image to that directory:
>
>   ```
>   cp /mnt/LiveISO/KNOPPIX/* /mnt/hda4/KNOPPIX/
>   ```
> - copy kernel and initrd files to yor boot device:
>
>   ```
>   cp /mnt/LiveISO/boot/* /boot
>   ```
> - Grub:
>
>   ```
>   title KNOPPIX  
>   root (hd0,0)  
>   kernel /linux26 ramdisk_size=100000 fromhd=/dev/hda4  
>   initrd /minirt26.gz  
>   savedefault  
>   boot
>   ```
> - Lilo:
>
>   ```
>   image=/boot/linux26  
>   initrd=/boot/minirt26.gz  
>   label=KNOPPIX  
>   append="ramdisk_size=100000 fromhd=/dev/hda4"
>   ```
>
> The basic idea is that you copy the contents of the iso to a
>   partition. Then, in your current linux os, you copy the kernel and
>   initrd images from the iso to your current boot directory. Last, you
>   edit LILO so that it points to the kernel and initrd images you just
>   copied, and make sure you append the "fromhd" line so that the
>   "livecd" will know where the rest of the knoppix files are. I know
>   that similar instructions worked with kanotix as well (which makes
>   sense since it is knoppix based). The only possible problem for other
>   isos (say non-livecds, for example) is that they may not have a
>   "fromhd" option the way knoppix distros do.

Found here: [Boot ISO image from hard disk?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/boot-iso-image-from-hard-disk-294744/#post1614000)

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing it, but could you explain how what you copy-pasted answers the question here, specifically?

Comment: He used `dd` to make a bit-for-bit copy of his iso onto the /dev/sda5 partition.  What he needs to do is copy specific files from the iso as well as other files from his existing install.  It's also set up to boot directly from the partition without going through /dev/sda3 first.

Unless he's trying to recover his /dev/sda1 partition with the newest install ISO, why would he want to do this?

Comment: The reason I am booting through /dev/sda3 is incase I mess up my bootloader on /dev/sda1. I will have to try your idea and see if it works. BTW slhck, he is suggesting an alternate method that will not give me an error.

Comment: What I can't figure out is why you can use dd to burn iso's to USB, but not hard drives?

Comment: Possibly the difference of reading a USB drive as a CD-ROM vs reading an HDD as a CD-ROM.

Answer (score 0):

I wish to give a clear answer to the original question, restated here as
"Why after dd_bitcopied_isoimage to /dev/sda5, is isolinux.bin missing or corrupted?" (no ersatz proposition to solve without answering!)

isolinux.bin is a bootloader for isofs_image. When the isoimage is created by mkisofs (or any clone like genisoimage, wodim, etc.) or more recent xorriso the physical position of isolinux.bin on that isofsimage is hard-coded into the master mbr or isohybrid-mbr, so that at boot the BIOS or similar firmware has access to it.

`dd isoimage` to `/dev/sda`  keeps that exact position so it can boot.

`dd isoimage` to `/dev/sda5` keeps that position with respect to `/dev/sda5` but no more to `/dev/sda` where the mbr sits!!!
Simply experiment with:

```
qemu-system-x_YYYY  /dev/sda5
```

to understand it!